# Jinija2 Template to Django Template

Tags: python-3.x, django-templates, jinja2

how to convert this code from jinja2 template to django template

```
`{% if (request.endpoint == 'venues') or
            (request.endpoint == 'search_venues') or
            (request.endpoint == 'show_venue') %}
          <form class="search" method="post" action="/venues/search">
            <input class="form-control"
              type="search"
              name="search_term"
              placeholder="Find a venue"
              aria-label="Search">
          </form>
          {% endif %}`
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove every parenthesis (that is not supported by Django Templates) after the `if` tag:

```
{% if request.endpoint == 'venues' or request.endpoint == 'search_venues' or request.endpoint == 'show_venue' %}
<form class="search" method="post" action="/venues/search">
  <input class="form-control"
         type="search"
         name="search_term"
         placeholder="Find a venue"
         aria-label="Search">
</form>
{% endif %}
```

Or if you want to make it more compact, pass the 'search endpoints' as a list variable to the template, e.g. `search_endpoints = ['venues', 'search_venues', 'search_venues']`, and you can use the [`in`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/builtins/#in-operator) operator for the same purpose:

```
{% if request.endpoint in search_endpoints %}
<form class="search" method="post" action="/venues/search">
  <input class="form-control"
         type="search"
         name="search_term"
         placeholder="Find a venue"
         aria-label="Search">
</form>
{% endif %}
```